# Which View Class should I use to?

Tags: iphone, class, uiwebview

I has been visiting your Blog regularly, and learned a lot from it. Now I'm troubled in a project. I hope you can give me some suggestion.

I want to make a interface of the news APP, which can shows the news title, content and pictures. The picture in the default condition will zoom out and appear with the news title and content in the interface. And the right corner of the picture has a symbal “plus”. When click “plus” ,the picture will show in full screen as in the attachment. Just like the following picture shows.

Which View Class should I use to make this interface.

http://images.weiphone.com/attachments/Day_100412/36_456164_b20b313f274de05.jpg

Answer (score 0):

For the actual content, it'd be best to use a `UIWebView`.  Then of course you need the `UINavigationController` and probably a `UITableViewController` to list the topics.

Comment: But how implement click “plus” , the picture will show in full screen as in the attachment. Which method can I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UIWebView (the best way to control all the formatting) then all of your content is HTML/Javascript/CSS.  You can include a javascript library (jQuery or whatever you like best) and then do your picture zoom in Javascript.  http://www.jqtouch.com/ is a library of UI elements for iPhone that might be helpful.

If all of your articles will have a picture, you could add a UIImageView to your view and then either scale it or load a separate image.  But if all of your content is coming from a web server, then it is probably easier to use the javascript approach.